# libboost ASIO. Simple asynchronous client server

Tags: c++, boost, asynchronous, boost-asio

I'm trying to implement a simple client/server in ASIO.

I'd like the following on the serverside:

`onConnect()`
`onDisconnect()`
`onMessageRecieved(char* data)`
`sendMessage(char* data)`

and on the client side:

`onConnect()`
`onDisconnect()`
`onMessageRecieved(char* data)`
`sendMessage(char* data)`

I didn't realise things would be so complicated.

Here's the simple echo server which I'm working off of:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>

using boost::asio::ip::tcp;

class session
{
public:
  session(boost::asio::io_service& io_service)
    : socket_(io_service)
  {
  }

  tcp::socket& socket()
  {
    return socket_;
  }

  void start()
  {
    socket_.async_read_some(boost::asio::buffer(data_, max_length),
        boost::bind(&session::handle_read, this,
          boost::asio::placeholders::error,
          boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
  }

  void handle_read(const boost::system::error_code& error,
      size_t bytes_transferred)
  {
    if (!error)
    {
      boost::asio::async_write(socket_,
          boost::asio::buffer(data_, bytes_transferred),
          boost::bind(&session::handle_write, this,
            boost::asio::placeholders::error));
    }
    else
    {
      delete this;
    }
  }

  void handle_write(const boost::system::error_code& error)
  {
    if (!error)
    {
      socket_.async_read_some(boost::asio::buffer(data_, max_length),
          boost::bind(&session::handle_read, this,
            boost::asio::placeholders::error,
            boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
    }
    else
    {
      delete this;
    }
  }

private:
  tcp::socket socket_;
  enum { max_length = 1024 };
  char data_[max_length];
};

class server
{
public:
  server(boost::asio::io_service& io_service, short port)
    : io_service_(io_service),
      acceptor_(io_service, tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(), port))
  {
    session* new_session = new session(io_service_);
    acceptor_.async_accept(new_session->socket(),
        boost::bind(&server::handle_accept, this, new_session,
          boost::asio::placeholders::error));
  }

  void handle_accept(session* new_session,
      const boost::system::error_code& error)
  {
    if (!error)
    {
      new_session->start();
      new_session = new session(io_service_);
      acceptor_.async_accept(new_session->socket(),
          boost::bind(&server::handle_accept, this, new_session,
            boost::asio::placeholders::error));
    }
    else
    {
      delete new_session;
    }
  }

private:
  boost::asio::io_service& io_service_;
  tcp::acceptor acceptor_;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  try
  {
    if (argc != 2)
    {
      std::cerr << "Usage: async_tcp_echo_server <port>\n";
      return 1;
    }

    boost::asio::io_service io_service;

    using namespace std; // For atoi.
    server s(io_service, atoi(argv[1]));

    io_service.run();
  }
  catch (std::exception& e)
  {
    std::cerr << "Exception: " << e.what() << "\n";
  }

  return 0;
}
```

I can telnet into this server and everything is echoed.

Now I'd like to wrap up this code in `onConnect()`, `onDisconnect()`, `onMessageReceived(char* data)`, etc. Similar to the way things are done in Node.js!

Has anyone got any pointers in this regard?

Comment: You're asking for a significant amount of code to be written for you.  What have you tried so far?

Comment: Not much really. I've tried to intercept the handle_read and handle_write functions to no avail... I'd appreciate any pointers you might have in this regard. It would be really nice to wrap up all that ASIO stuff into an easy-to-use class. I'm prepared to put several hours into this.

Comment: I've written code that does exactly this, unfortunately it belongs to the company and isn't mine to share.  Not sure I can give an easy overview that would be an appropriate "answer" but I'll try.

Comment: Not appropriate for an answer but:    Using `boost::asio` along with the asynchronous functions such as `async_connect()', 'async_read()` and `async_write()` allow you to provide a handler (or callback) function that gets called when the operation completes.  It's relatively trivial to write a class that encapsulates this functionality, and has the necessary `On<Action>` functions that you are requesting using this method.

Comment: That's really useful stuff Chad. Thanks so much. I'll report back when I make some progress.

Comment: [Thinking Asynchronously: Designing Applications with Boost.Asio](http://blip.tv/boostcon/thinking-asynchronously-designing-applications-with-boost-asio-5250947), [Why C++0x is the Awesomest Language for Network Programming](https://blip.tv/boostcon/why-c-0x-is-the-awesomest-language-for-network-programming-5368225)

Comment: @EvgenyPanasyuk: Thank you for the links. They are helpful for understanding more of the architecture behind `boost::asio`. But I am still missing the "big picture", i.e., how do I use the API to make my life simpler compared to the synchronous operations on BSD sockets in a background thread?

Comment: @user8472 At the end of second talk he describes approach based on [stackless coroutines](https://github.com/chriskohlhoff/awesome/blob/master/server.cpp). `Boost.Asio` also has [`example`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/http/server4/server.cpp). Another way is based on stack-full coroutines, `Boost.Coroutine` has [`asio` example](https://github.com/boostorg/coroutine/blob/master/example/asio/stream_server.cpp). Code with coroutines looks like synchronized, but in fact is asynchronous: `do{ getline(s,msg); cout << msg << std::endl; } while ("exit" != msg);`

Comment: @user8472 btw, I think it is better start separate Q. Because you want some general tutorial, while OP needs just solution to his specific problem.

Comment: @EvgenyPanasyuk I think you have a good point. Actually, the question of the OP is very close to what I was looking for myself. So there would have been little I could ask about without duplicating the question. A general tutorial on how and why `boost::asio` adds more than a different syntax to functionality that exists elsewhere also addresses the OQ. Your references to the videos are interesting and your references to coroutines are even more enlightening. I was unaware what `boost` offered in that area -- thank you for your help!

Comment: @user8472 stackfull coroutines at Boost were appeared only in the latest version - [1.53](http://www.boost.org/users/history/version_1_53_0.html)

Answer (score 3):

- `onMessageReceived()` can be called from `handle_read`.
- `onConnect()` can be called from `start`.
- `onDisconnect()` can be called in the destructor of the `session` class.

For the bounty questions:

The `io_service.run()` can be placed in its own thread.

[As per the documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/asio_handler_invoke.html)

> Certain guarantees are made on when the handler may be invoked, in particular that a handler can only be invoked from a thread that is currently calling run() on the corresponding io_service object.

Asynchronous sending and receiving can be handled by this single thread. This simplifies thread safety because all the callbacks will be running in succession. This is probably the simplest way of using boost asio.

For calls coming from outside of the `run()` thread, you can schedule a callback (e.g. [deadline_timer](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/deadline_timer.html)), from the 'outside thread' for immediate calling to simplify your thread safety handling. e.g.

```
    boost::asio::deadline_timer timer(io_service);
    timer.expires_from_now(boost::posix_time::seconds(0));
    timer.async_wait(boost::bind(&MyClass::MyCallback, this, boost::asio::placeholders::error);
```

The `io_service` object will call the handler for you in a thread-safe fashion as soon as it has a chance. This way, your asio code can behave as if there was only a single thread in the entire system.

If multiple threads are required or preferred (e.g. Take advantage of multi-core) you may call `run()` on multiple thread. Handlers will have to be re-entrant. You may also want to use a [strand](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service__strand.html) for certain operations.

Otherwise, regular thread safety rules applies.

Comment: Could you be more explicit about how I would schedule a `deadline_timer` from the 'outside' thread? Is there any documentation on this?

Comment: And what is the advantage of these asynchronous calls over "regular" synchronous calls in a background thread (which is also possible to be done with `boost::asio`?

Comment: The advantage is blocking calls vs non-blocking calls. One could also decide on a different I/O strategy. There are multiple approaches and you can mix them too. I believe that would be a question on its own; See http://www.kegel.com/c10k.html

Comment: This is exactly the point I seem to be unable to get: The `async_*` calls are running in a thread that is blocked by `run()` method. To solve this, I put this call in a separate, dedicated thread and all operations will run in that thread without blocking my main thread. So far, so good. **BUT**, if I need to use a separate thread, then I could equally well use a synchronous API on that thread. That would make my life (somewhat) easier and that is exactly what I did before with BSD sockets. So am I missing something about `boost::asio` that could make my life easier?

Comment: For example, let's take a TCP server. You would need on thread per client with the blocking calls. Otherwise if you read on a socket that the client is not writing all other clients would be delayed. This is why you use async i/o; to serve multiple clients in one thread. If your application is only a server, you would simply call the blocking run() in your main thread. Let boost asio dispatch for you. If your application is doing more then this, you can also call asio run on a different thread that will be blocked. Asio is flexible, you could also call it in multiple threads.

Comment: Note that with BSD sockets you would also have to loop around select or poll. In effect, you would also have a thread similar to asio run. Perhaps thinking of this loop being inside of asio run() will make more sense to you?

Comment: Yes, it does! I believe that you just made it clear to me what I was missing -- the explanation *why* these asynchronous calls are useful. In connection with the coroutines mentioned by Evgeny Panasyuk in the comment above the design actually becomes quite powerful and flexible. I would conclude that for a server with a single client the asynchronous calls are a possible solution, but are not superior to a synchronous design. For a server with multiple clients and multiple communication states, the design gets very powerful and superior.